# What are the drawbacks to calling $digest from outside angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend

I'm working on a game that only uses Angular for it's user interface. The game code has a loop that runs every second. To keep the UI in sync I am directly calling $digest from outside of Angular.

```
//from angular code
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('acp', acp);

acp.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$window'];

function acp($rootScope, $window){
    var service = $window.ACP = {
        heartBeat: heartBeat,
        rootScope: $rootScope
    };

    return service;

    function heartBeat(){
        $rootScope.$$phase || $rootScope.$digest();
    }
}

//from game code
setInterval(function(){
    //do stuff within game
    updateResources();
    window.ACP.heartBeat();
}.bind(this), 1000);
```

For a simple front-end game, is this permissible? Can you suggest a better way for communication between my angular ui and the game code? I have another global variable that holds the state of my game that both Angular and the game code consume straight from the window object because I quite like the convenience of object references and the direct nature. I understand the bad juju of using globals but I feel like once you step into game territory, the lines can get a little blurred. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you know you can inject $window into your controller? It provides an Angular wrapper object around the global window object.

Comment: Yeah I know about $window. I updated the example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use setTimeout. Angular provides a wrapper`$timeout` that would take care of running the digest cycle which means you don't have to do it manually.

As for the communication between your game code and angular ui, here are some recommendations

> - You could use [`factories`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) or [`services`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers) where you can store the state of the game (instead of using any global variables)
> - You can also use `websockets` so instead of making a call every 1 second, you would establish a socket connection with your backend api (or game code) and they talk to each other without the additional overhead of calling your api every 1 second. You can start with [`socket.io`](http://socket.io) to accomplish this
> - You could also use `$rootScope` to store the value but have this as your last option
>
> Note: You are using a setTimeout. For triggering something at an interval, use `$interval`. But then, analyze the above options and figure out which one suits you best.